# Sum of transformations - consequences

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Well, in matrix-vector transformation, I know that if we take the composition of a transformation, like:

$T(x) = A\cdot x$
and $T$ maps from $R^n$ to $R^m$

$S(x) = B\cdot x$
and $S$ maps from $R^m$ to $R^p$

Then the composition $T(S(x))$ maps from $R^n$ to $R^p$, then we can define the matrix multiplication by:
$$T(S(x)) = B\cdot (A\cdot x) = (B A)\cdot x$$

This makes sense to me. What I don't understand, are the consequences of summing two transformations this way:

$T(x) + S(x) = (S+T)(x) = (B+A)\cdot x$

What are the consequences of this sum?

Comment: Well it's wrong actually, the domain of the two transformation is different. Also it should be $S(T(x))$ not the other way around (and also $BAx$

Comment: @Horstenson yeah you're right, just fixed

Comment: Also the $T(S(x))$ should be $S(T(x))$. Could you elaborate on what your question is? The sum at the end is not defined as I said above, so what is the question?